# Authenticate user without username and password , but using a token in spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have an android client which doesn't implement any username and password login, it user OTP for login. So i have only firebase userID. How can i configure `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to use this `firebase userID` to authenticate user and we don't have front-end  website for logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure spring security to use a custom autenticationProvider, and use firebase API to verify your tokens sent as a header of you request, have a look at this example [HERE](https://awaters1.github.io/Spring-Boot-Single-Sign-On-Firebase-Part-2/)